# How to start IncallUi activity from your app on Android

Tags: android

Whenever a user receives a call, my app comes into foreground. I have 2 buttons accept and reject. I can reject the call on click of my button programmatically but it's not possible to accept a call programmatically. So I want to navigate user to InCallUi (Android Activity to handle incoming call) when he click accept button. Is there a way this can be achieved?

Comment: Just dont push yourself into foreground when not rejecting the call?

Comment: When you are in some App, the call comes in as a Notification. Also, the app is kind of Video Caller Id, so when you get a call you see a video. You can reject it, but the accepting does not work programmatically.

Comment: this is old but, did you achieved something?